# Java - resultado incorrecto de assertEqual en test

Tags: java, testing

estoy haciendo un método que a partir de un input de un dorsal, nombre y apellido, devuelve un valor de la siguiente forma:
DORSAL2020_ICASTRO

Para ello, el dorsal debe tener la condición de ser un string de letras y 4 números al final, la inicial de un nombre y el apellido completo. En caso de tener el apellido 2 palabras (separadas por '_'), se coge sólo la primera.

Para conseguir 'DORSAL2020_ICASTRO', por ejemplo sería:

- Dorsal = DORSAL2020
- nombre = Ignacio
- apellido = CASTRO_ALVAREZ

```
    public String olimpicGames;
    public void setDorsal(String olimpicGames, String name, String surname){

        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile ("^[A-Z].*[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$.*");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(olimpicGames);
        if (mat.matches()){
            this.olimpicGames = olimpicGames + "_" + name.substring(0, 1) + surname.substring(0, surname.indexOf("_"));
        }else{
            System.out.println("[ERROR] Athlete's dorsal pattern is incorrect");
            this.olimpicGames = null;                  // esto es correcto? Cómo devuelve el valor NULL? quitar void?
        }
    }

    public String getDorsal(){
        return olimpicGames;
    }
```

Los test que ejecuto son:

```
    void testDorsal() {
        athlete.setDorsal("TOKIO2020", "Fran", "GIL_GARCIA");
        assertEquals("TOKIO2020_FGIL", athlete.getDorsal());

        athlete.setDorsal("2020A", "Fran", "GIL_GARCIA");
        assertEquals("[ERROR] Athlete's dorsal pattern is incorrect", outContent.toString().replaceAll("\n|\r\n", System.getProperty("line.separator").trim()));
        restoreStreams();
    }
```

Al ejecutar, no indica que en el test `athlete.setDorsal("2020A", "Fran", "GIL_GARCIA");` debe mostrar el mensaje de pantalla *"[ERROR] Athlete's dorsal pattern is incorrect"*

Añado el outContent:

```
private ByteArrayOutputStream outContent;
    private final PrintStream originalOut = System.out;

    Athlete athlete;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUpStreams() {
        outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void restoreStreams() {
        System.setOut(originalOut);
    }
```

Por qué no?

Gracias.

Comment: 1) ¿Cuál es el contenido de outContent?, ¿dónde lo asignas? y, sobre todo 2) ¿Por qué no lanzas simplemente una excepción? Comerte el error e imprimir un mensaje por consola es en general muy mal diseño: vinculas tu lógica al IU (¿qué pasa si usas esa clase en una aplicación swing?) y además simplemente ignoras el error.

Comment: @SJuan76, estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que no puedo añadir excepciones (tampoco tengo tantos conocimientos) y más adelante deberé hacer el mismo ejercicio pero añadiendo dichas excepciones. El outContent está cogido de otros test que me venían por defecto y para este caso, debo hacerlo yo. Todos los casos en los que hay error esperado, está indicado así el mensaje

Comment: @SJuan76, acabo de añadir el outContent, por algún motivo daba error pero ya no. Ahora tengo otra cuestión pero eso ya es otro tema y no este. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun las buenas practicas con los Test se deben de probar casos individuales y en tu código esta probando 2 escenarios en un mismo Test, uno correcto y el otro incorrecto, aparte si son POJO como Athlete procura instanciarlo dentro del test a menos que se deba utilizar de forma global, los test corregidos quedarían de la siguiente forma:

```
  void testDorsal_correct_format_ok() {
      Athlete athlete = new Athlete();
      athlete.setDorsal("TOKIO2020", "Fran", "GIL_GARCIA");
      Assert.assertEquals("TOKIO2020_FGIL", athlete.getDorsal());
  }

  void testDorsal_incorrect_format_error() {
      Athlete athlete2 = new Athlete();
      athlete2.setDorsal("2020A", "Fran", "GIL_GARCIA");
      Assert.assertEquals("[ERROR] Athlete's dorsal pattern is incorrect", athlete.getDorsal());
  }
```

Como no has colocado el código de la variable `outContent` la he eliminado del proceso, pero no veo la utilidad de tenerla.

Comment: el ```outContent``` lo acabo de añadir, perdona. El problema está solucionado ya. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validar en vez de un mensaje que imprimes por consola(cosa que me es raro) que el dorsal sea null con `assertNull`, ya que la única forma de sea null al llamar a `setDorsal` es si entra en el `else`